# python win32api fails after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pyinstaller

i have a problem which occurs after i use pyinstaller to form a executable.
The piece of code use the function win32api.GetShortPathName to check if the file exists on a path with long filename, running the python file alone is no problem. After using pyinstaller the program fails in the same situation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycopy.py", line 32, in cp
pywintypes.error: (3, 'GetShortPathNameW', 'Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "pycopy.py", line 131, in download
  File "pycopy.py", line 83, in copyit
  File "pycopy.py", line 36, in cp
pywintypes.error: (3, 'GetShortPathNameW', 'Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.')
```

The error means in english: System cannot find path

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. How do you specify the file path? Are you using relative path? Could you please share a minimal sample(without privacy information) you have tried?

Comment: It is general problem: somewere in *pycopy.py* you are trying to access path that does not exist. Make sure that your long path really accessible from exe.

Comment: This is the test path, it contains all symbols which will be need in later usecases "\\as02.company.com\word\word\word\word123\word\word word\PyCopy\wsedrftghjnmkwsedrfghnjmksedcrfvghbnjmk,l\wsedrftghjnmkwsedrfghnjmksedcrfvghbnjmk,läö§$%&(wsedrftghjnmkwsedrfghnjmksedcrfvghbnjmk,l\cfgjhnkmedtcfgvbjhnk43d56f7ghi8jopkdft\sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss\234567t8zu9jikoserdtfghjkasdfsdfsdfsdfsdffhbb\q2w3e4r5t6z7u8i9ow3e4rt6zu7i89ope34r5t6z7u8i\ertzuiodwiokdwpokdwpdjkwpjdwpjdpwjdpwjdpwjd#ääüääüäüä\a.txt".  The path is in a csv file and will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later), Add the `longPathAware` element to the application manifest:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

Or add "`\\?\`" prefix to specify an extended-length path in the Unicode version of winapi, For example, "`\\?\D:\very long path`".